# Git fails to merge or pull local repos

Tags: git

I have been working on a project involving two computers. I have been using Git to manage the code and sync it, but now, when I try to use Git pull, it fails, saying that there are conflicts and telling me to resolve them.

So, my questions are: What causes this? What is a conflict? How can I fix it? Can I force Git to pull?

Any help is appreciated.

Sorry, I'm kind of a noob...

Also, I'm using Linux.

Thank you!

Comment: you need to resolve conflicts in your code , then test that it works well or not then only your will be able to push the clean working code.

Comment: Oops, sorry  I forgot to include a question... Please read it again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A conflict is that git finds that the merge underlying the pull you want to make, will result in loss of code because they "touch" the same lines so a change done on one computer will eradicate the changes done on the other computer.

You normally do not want this.  The default behavior of git is to give you the necessary information and require you to resolve the conflicts manually.  When done, you need to commit the final result causing git to consider the conflict resolved.

Your wording indicates that you are unfamiliar with these concepts.  I would suggest studying the "Pro Git" book, especially the "Basic branching and merging" chapter available at https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Comment: Okay, thank you. So, if I changed a line on both the computers, I just have to change one back to how it was before?

Comment: Identical lines should merge automatically.  I would suggest learning how to fix conflicts instead.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much! This was quite a fast answer! I honestly had no clue that there was a book on it  Oops!

Comment: git is quite advanced - you will most likely need to read documentation anyway.

Comment: I've read the manpage and I had a basic understanding (it was good enough before now) but it doesn't describe conflicts... Sorry!

Comment: Good luck.  The fun comes when you get to rewriting history :)

Comment: Thanks x3 The weird part about all of this is it's basically the only thing that I don't know how to do with Git XD